# Simple Union, but

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm neither a programmer nor a SQL expert and I'm currently working on a little MS Access Database and I am at a point where I'm stuck. I know, it's Access but it's fine for this job.

So here's my problem.
I have two tables:

```
Table A:
Order - ProjectNr - Description - CompanyID
A111    444         xxx           999
A333    444         xxx           999
A444    444         xxx           999
...
```

```
Table B:
Order - ProjectNr - Description - CompanyID
B222    444         xxx           999
B333    444         xxx           999
...
```

so both tables are pretty much the same BUT the OrderNr is different. They Start different but after the first character they're the same.
Now I want to combine these two tables - done that by a simple UNION.

The thing is, IF there is already a ProjectNr which has a OrderNr Starting with "A", I don't want the "B" OrderNr. in the Union result.

So in the example from above the result should be:

```
Order - ProjectNr - Description - CompanyID
A111    444         xxx           999
B222    444         xxx           999
A333    444         xxx           999
A444    444         xxx           999
```

NO B333 because there's already an A333 entry.

With my simple UNION I, of course, get A333 and B333.

Could you please give me some help how to do this in MS Access 2016?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from TableA
union all
select b.* from TableB as b
where not exists (
  select 1 from TableA as a
  where mid(a.order, 2) = mid(b.order, 2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> so both tables are pretty much the same BUT the OrderNr is different

Given this premise I would question the DB structure before proceeding. 
Did you design the DB tables? Do you REALLY need to have two tables with the same kind of data? It seems a single table with an extra field would work better.
Something like:

```
Table A:
OrderCode    Order  ProjectNr   Description   CompanyID
A            111    444         xxx           999
A            333    444         xxx           999
A            444    444         xxx           999
B            222    444         xxx           999
B            333    444         xxx           999
```

Which in turn should go under [normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

The 'not exists' solution works but is not ideal especially if it were to be applied on large tables as it will not use the index tables leading to poor performance.